# react-native customize android toolbar

Tags: android, react-native

I have a toolbar that currently looks like this

```
<ToolbarAndroid
        title='WWF'
        style={styles.toolbar}
        navIcon={require("./App/assets/logo.png")}
        logo={require("./App/assets/logo.png")}
        actions={[{title: 'list', show: 'always'}, {title: 'partners', show: 'always'}, {title: 'about',  show: 'always'}]}
        onActionSelected={this.onActionSelected} />
```

Is it possible to change the size and position of the logo?  Currently it sits with a margin on the left and I would like to make it sit on the left corner of the screen and possible make it wider.

Also is it possible to have two images next to each other as the logo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `<ToolbarAndroid />` can be customized. You are probably better off doing your own component with `<View />` to suit your needs, or take a look at the [react-native-navbar](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-navbar) library.

Answer (score 0):

try to this code for implement Toolbar

```
ender () {
    const { title, onLeftPress, showDrawer } = this.props
    return (
      <Icon.ToolbarAndroid
        navIconName={showDrawer ? 'md-menu' : 'md-arrow-back'}
        onIconClicked={onLeftPress}
        style={styles.toolbar}
        titleColor={'white'}
        title={title}
      />
    )
  }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  toolbar: {
    backgroundColor: 'blusteel',
    height: 54,
    position: 'absolute', 
    top: 0, 
    left: 0, 
    width: Dimensions.get('window').width
  }
})
```